# Firestore simple collectionGroup makes the function timeout

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is scheduled to run every 2 mins. 
I am currently testing the function using an Http one, and trying to run a simple `collectionGroup` query as follows

**Update 1**
I updated my code to handle `offset` and `limit` but now it's working fine for the first record by then hangs while fetching the second record.

please check the snippet

```
/* eslint-disable promise/no-nesting */

/**
 * @description
 * This module will send out emails to different users who have alerts not sent out yet
 * @algorithm
 * 1 - Get all alerts where sent = false 
 * 2 - Send out those alerts via the email module. 
 */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { db } = require("../helpers/firestore");
// console.log('admin: ', admin);
let _allUserAlerts = [];
let counter = 0;

exports.sendEmailsToUsers = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 2 minutes")
  .onRun(context => {
    return sendEmailsToUsers(context);
  });

exports.testSendEmailsToUsers = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return sendEmailsToUsers("hello");
});

async function sendEmailsToUsers(context) {
  try {
    console.log("function execution")
    let alerts = await db
      .collectionGroup("alerts")
      .where("sent", "==", false)
      .limit(1)
      .offset(counter)
      .get();

    alerts.forEach(_alert => {
      if (_alert.exists) {
        console.log("alert exists")
        _allUserAlerts.push(_alert.data());
        counter++;
        return sendEmailsToUsers()
      } else {
        console.log("alert ends")
        sendAlertsToEmail(_allUserAlerts)
      }
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

async function sendAlertsToEmail(alerts) {
  console.log('alerts: ', alerts);
}
```

**Old code**

```
/* eslint-disable promise/no-nesting */

/**
 * @description
 * This module will send out emails to different users who have alerts not sent out yet
 * @algorithm
 * 1 - Get all alerts where sent = false 
 * 2 - Send out those alerts via the email module. 
 */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { db } = require("../helpers/firestore");
const { Email } = require("../EmailModule");

const { groupBy } = require("../helpers/groupBy");

exports.sendEmailsToUsers = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 2 minutes")
  .onRun(context => {
    return sendEmailsToUsers(context);
  });

async function sendEmailsToUsers(context) {
  try {
    console.log("function execution")
    let alerts = await db
      .collectionGroup("alerts")
      .where("sent", "==", false)
      .get();
    console.log('alerts: ', alerts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

This is literally the entire code in the function, but the function times out and I don't get to the `log()` of `alerts`. 
I am not getting what could be the problem here ? Any thing I might be missing or not getting here ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That is not literally the entire code, at least not in the sense that would be helpful for use on Stack Overflow.  Please edit the question to include the function definition as well - you should include the entire contents of the file so we can see what kind of function this is, and explain how you are invoking it.  An MCVE will be helpful.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Okay I've added the function definition as well. See if there's an anomaly ?

Comment: What exactly is in the log, if not what you expect?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The problem is the function just stops on let alerts = await db part and times out after 60 seconds. The console part is just to see if the code is running or not.

Comment: Could you share the log anyway, even if you think it doesn't matter?

Comment: I am getting this in the logs:
NOTICE: Longjohn is known to cause CPU usage due to its extensive data collection during runtime.
It generally should not be used in production applications.

Comment: How many documents do you think match this query?  How big is this collection?

Comment: Alerts collection is present in all user collection docs, so each user will have around 2000+ alerts so we're looking at may be 10,000 - 15000 + documents here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to upgrade the current node version. 
By default Cloud functions work on `Node 8` which has stopped support from the official node.js team. So when I upgrade to `Node 10` it started working again perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the process simply takes more than 60s. You can increase the [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) of the cloud function. You can raise it up to 9 minutes and it should work.

Otherwise the problem does not seems to be from the function itself. The issue may be somewhere here : `const { db } = require("../helpers/firestore");` . "db" is not coming, and that's way your code stops at `let alerts = await db` .

Comment: I tried extending function time to 9 minutes but still it timed out. 
The strange part is that it runs fine for some collection and for some it just times out

Also I am getting this in the logs:
NOTICE: Longjohn is known to cause CPU usage due to its extensive data collection during runtime.
It generally should not be used in production applications.

Comment: Maybe you are hitting the quotas for CF? Take a look on this list : https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be requesting too much data to transmit and store in memory without problems.  I suggest [paginating](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) your data with `limit()` instead so that you can batch process results without exceeding the limits of Cloud Functions server instances (which are quite limited).  Start small and work your way up.

Comment: I just did that, it works fine for the first document but then hangs when fetching the next one. I've updated my question for the updated code.